# change the default font to mcode font for Matlab file in XeLatex

Tags: xetex

I am writing my thesis and got stuck up with this problem.

I am using Times New Roman as default font by loading

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

and I compile the TEX file using XeLaTeX. In the appendix I need to put my MATLAB code. I have used `\usepackage{mcode}`.

When I run the file using XeLaTeX the fonts in my MATLAB code go to Times New Roman. But, I need the MATLAB code to be in default MATLAB font. How should I locally change the font?

Answer (score 1):

First of all that shouldn't be the case. By default `mcode` uses the font Courier. See line 178-179 in `mcode.sty`:

```
% default font
\def\lstbasicfont{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize}
```

So what you want do to is redefine `\lstbasicfont`. As far as I remember MATLAB uses Helvetica as default font. So just add

```
\newfontfamily{\helvetica}{Helvetica}
\def\lstbasicfont{\helvetica\footnotesize}
```

after loading `mcode`.